# How to count list inside dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to get from the below data set named "current data"

```
current_data <-
  tribble(
    ~ID, ~grade_Q1, ~points_Q1,
    "1", c("D-", "C-", "C-", "C-"), c(1, 2, 2, 2), 
    "2", c("A", "B", "B+", "B+"), c(4, 3, 3, 3),
  )
```

to the below dataset named "updated_data"

```
updated_data <-
  tribble(
    ~ID, ~grade_Q1, ~points_Q1, ~n_grades,
    "1", "D- C C- C-", "1 2 2 2", 4,
    "2", "A B B+ B+ A", "4 3 3 3 4", 5
  )
```

The "n_grades" column is literally just a count of the number of letter grades in the "grade_q1" column. Anyone have any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `lengths` of 'grade_Q1' to create the `n_grades`, then loop over the `list` columns with `map`, concatenate into a single string with `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
current_data %>% 
  mutate(n_grades = lengths(grade_Q1),
    grade_Q1 = map_chr(grade_Q1, str_c, collapse= ' '), 
    points_Q1 = map_chr(points_Q1, str_c, collapse = ' '))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  ID    grade_Q1    points_Q1 n_grades
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>        <int>
#1 1     D- C- C- C- 1 2 2 2          4
#2 2     A B B+ B+ A 4 3 3 3 4        5
```

---

If there are many columns, it can be simplified with `across`

```
current_data %>% 
  mutate(n_grades = lengths(grade_Q1),
     across(c(grade_Q1, points_Q1), ~ map_chr(., str_c, collapse= ' ')))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
current_data$n_grades <- lengths(current_data$grade_Q1)

current_data[c("grade_Q1", "points_Q1")] <- 
  lapply(current_data[c("grade_Q1", "points_Q1")], 
      sapply, paste, collapse= ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(current_data)[
  ,
  c(
    lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0(unlist(x), collapse = " ")),
    n_grades = lengths(grade_Q1)
  ),
  ID
][]
```

gives

```
   ID    grade_Q1 points_Q1 n_grades
1:  1 D- C- C- C-   1 2 2 2        4
2:  2 A B B+ B+ A 4 3 3 3 4        5
```